# Tensorflow KMeansClustering training on CPU and not GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am currently running tensorflow-gpu 1.8 with cuda 9.0. When I train the model below, I notice that my CPU usage is 99% but my Tesla M60 usage is at 0%.

import tensorflow as tf

```
tf.test.gpu_device_name()

def train(tfidf_matrix, num_clusters):
    # Convert sparse matrix to dense matrix
    points = tfidf_matrix.todense()

    tf.device('/gpu:0')

    def input_fn():
        return tf.train.limit_epochs(tf.convert_to_tensor(points, dtype=tf.float32), num_epochs=1)

    kmeans = tf.contrib.factorization.KMeansClustering(num_clusters=num_clusters, use_mini_batch=False)
    num_iterations = 100

    kmeans.train(input_fn=input_fn, steps=num_iterations)
    print('score:', kmeans.score(input_fn))

    # map the input points to their clusters
    cluster_indices = list(kmeans.predict_cluster_index(input_fn))

    return kmeans, cluster_indices
```

I can't seem to get the model to run on gpu. I tried doing this:

```
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    kmeans.train(input_fn)
```

but it still runs on cpu.
When I run tf.test.gpu_device_name() I get this

`2018-07-18 15:28:47.105452: I c:\users\user\source\repos\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1392] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Tesla M60 major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.1775
pciBusID: 0000:00:1e.0
totalMemory: 7.44GiB freeMemory: 7.12GiB
2018-07-18 15:28:47.105846: I c:\users\user\source\repos\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1471] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-07-18 15:28:47.852029: I c:\users\user\source\repos\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:952] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-07-18 15:28:47.852268: I c:\users\user\source\repos\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:958]      0 
2018-07-18 15:28:47.852440: I c:\users\user\source\repos\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:971] 0:   N 
2018-07-18 15:28:47.852859: I c:\users\user\source\repos\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1084] Created TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0 with 6874 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla M60, pci bus id: 0000:00:1e.0, compute capability: 5.2

Comment: [This GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12388) found by googling your problem has a number of suggestions you could try. Check that you've installed your drivers correctly as described there. Also, if you installed via `pip`, make sure you installed `tensorflow-gpu`, not `tensorflow`.

Comment: @ChandlerWatson I followed the steps for version 1.8 with cuda 9.0 and it still shows 0% utilization on GPU-Z

Comment: Are you able to run any TF examples (maybe something for vision that might make strong use of GPU) and replicate the issue?

Comment: @ChandlerWatson When I run various TF models, it seems to utilize the GPU. It's only when I use KMeansClustering that I don't use the GPU

Comment: Ah. In that case, it’s likely there still isn’t a GPU kernel for it. It’s worth checking the source, but it’s probably still the case that TF supports KMeansClustering only on CPU.